# Django: I need to supersede a particular Python module in a no-longer-maintained package

Tags: python, django

Well, I *think* that the "Pinax" package is no longer maintained ...

Anyway, it refers to a now-deprecated `django.utils.tzinfo` package.  I need to make a one-line change to one source module, and then cause *that* version of the package to be loaded instead of the one in the module directory.  Is there a generic way in Django to do that sort of thing?  (I know that some *packages* such as the Machina forum software can do this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would uninstall the module you want to modify from your virtual environment, then fork the module to your github, commit your changes, and install it to your virtual environment from your github like

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/path/to/repo
```

Comment: I agree that this is probably the wisest and most robust solution.  I'll need to consider exactly how this applies to the (PythonAnywhere ...) cloud environment, but I'll accept this as "the right answer."  Thank you for your counsel.

Comment: ... although in my case the git repository is local.

Comment: you could do this for a local repo: cd your-local-repo
pip install -e .   but if you have to keep the repo local obviously installing this project on other machines is going to be more difficult